# MLE of exponential distribution in R

Tags: r, exponential, mle

If we generate a random vector from the exponential distribution:

```
exp.seq = rexp(1000, rate=0.10) # mean = 10
```

Now we want to use the previously generated vector `exp.seq` to re-estimate lambda
So we define the log likelihood function:

```
fn <- function(lambda){
length(exp.seq)*log(lambda)-lambda*sum(exp.seq)
}
```

Now `optim` or `nlm` I'm getting very different value for lambda:

```
optim(lambda, fn) # I get here 3.877233e-67
nlm(fn, lambda) # I get here 9e-07
```

I used the same technique for the normal distribution and it works fine. So where is the mistake here?
I'm using my own definition for the exponential distribution because I will need to change it later.

Comment: Both `optim` and `nlm` do minimization by default. You want maximization. Alternatively you could flip the sign of your function as well.

Comment: @MrFlick indeed this was the problem. Thanks for the quick response.